# libcurl c++ curl_easy_init not working

Tags: c++, curl, mingw, libcurl

I just tried setting up curl for the first time using windows + mingw + eclipse juno + curl 7.29. I managed to get it to compile and build fine. I've added the two flags for lcurl and lcurldll.
For some reason though the following does not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
 cout << "L1" << endl;
 CURL *curl;
 curl = curl_easy_init();
 cout << "L2" << endl;
}
```

Neither L1 nor L2 will print. If I comment out the easy_init line though it runs fine. 
I can't seem to find any similar posts, sorry if this is a dupe. Also, I can't step into anything as it dies as soon as I hit run. I'm sure its something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Service Release 1
Build id: 20120920-0800

curl version: 7.29.0 - SSL enabled 
URL: http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.29.0/dist-w32/curl-7.29.0-devel-mingw32.zip

as for mingw not sure which version I have, I just went to http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ and downloaded / installed the latest ver.

In eclipse, under MinGW C++ linker, I have curl and curldll for libraries. In misc I have the static flag - those are the only compiler settings I have changed.

Comment: This does not compile for me, at least `<iostream>` is missing. Are you sure that exactly this snippet of code compiles and runs and shows the mentioned behaviour?

Comment: sorry I left out the #include <iostream> from my sample I will update it. it does compile, and it does give me the output if the line is commented out.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget anything else? It compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: thats the problem. I can't think of anything else? I added the flags. Mingw has the libs. I checked that its the same version everywhere. It all builds and compiles fine. I'm wondering if its an eclipse or mingw issue, they are both 64 bit version. Is there anything else I need to add or include?

Comment: Versions of all included tools and libraries as well as the compile and linker commands /might/ give someone else a clue.

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me, but i just had to add `system("PAUSE")` at the end since the console close before i can see anything.

here's my code :

```
#include <curl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    cout << "L1" << endl;

    CURL *curl;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    cout << "L2" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

If you get the message "cannot open include file: 'curl.h': no such file or directory" or something like that, this is because you've missed something in the installation of curl.
It took me a long time to install it.

Comment: thank you, but system pause is not my issue. As I mentioned, it prints fine when the line is commented out, so it's not a matter of printing. I think it might be an issue with my installation, that's the part I'm struggling to figure out. I'll keep trying and post back when it is resolved.